# Is this matrix positive semidefinite (Symmetric matrix, with particular pattern)

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let's consider a symmetric matrix A.

If for each row, the diagonal entry is equal or larger than the magnitude of any other element, that is

$$a_{ii} \geq  |a_{ij}| \quad\text{for all rows } i \text{ and entries } j , \,$$

then the matrix is positive semi-definite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false, I've just this counterexample.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\
0.9 & 1 & 0.1 \\
0.9 & 0.1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
is indefinite, since the eigenvalues are $0.9$ and $(21 \pm \sqrt{649})/20$.

From this answer:
[Is this a positive semi- definite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/is-this-a-positive-semi-definite-matrix?rq=1)

Comment: Rounding off to integers looks more beautiful (with only zeros and ones).